SwiftUI AVPlayer not playing the video from an URL in TVOS Simulator
I have simple video player UI with A button and SwiftUI video player component. When I press the button the video doesn't play and it gives me following error in console.
               AQMEIO.cpp:198   timed out after 15.000s (0 0); suspension count=0 (IOSuspensions: )
 MEDeviceStreamClient.cpp:467   AQME Default-InputOutput: client stopping after failed start: <CA_UISoundClientBase@0x105eb4990>; running count now 0
     CA_UISoundClient.cpp:293   CA_UISoundClientBase::StartPlaying: AddRunningClient failed (status = -66681).
       MEMixerChannel.cpp:1006  MEMixerChannel::EnableProcessor: failed to open processor type 0x705f6571

Here is my code
struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    var videoID = ""
    @State var player = AVPlayer()
    var body: some View {
    
        VStack{
            Button(action: {
                player.play()
            }, label: {
               Text("Button")
            })
            VideoPlayer(player: player)
                 .frame(width: 500,height: 500)
            
                 .onAppear(perform: {
                     player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/cc8402e8c16cc8f36d3f63bd29eb82f99f4b5f88/accudvh5jy.mp4")!)
                
                })
        }
      
            
    }
}

#Preview {
    VideoPlayerView()
}


If you use @State with an object it must be optional and use an if in body
